# How to get Spark2.3 working in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter, apache-spark-2.0

I am struggling on getting Spark2.3 working in Jupyter Notebook now.

Currently I have kernel created as below:

1. create an environment file:

> ```
> $ cat rxie20181012-pyspark.yml
>
> name: rxie20181012-pyspark
>
> dependencies:
>
> - pyspark
> ```

2. create an environment based on the environment file

> conda env create -f rxie20181012-pyspark.yml

3. activate the new environment:

> source activate rxie20181012-pyspark

4. create kernel based on the conda env:

> sudo ./python -m ipykernel install --name rxie20181012-pyspark
>   --display-name "Python (rxie20181012-pyspark)"

5. kernel.json is as below:

> cat /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/rxie20181012-pyspark/kernel.json
>
> {
>
> "display_name": "Python (rxie20181012-pyspark)",
>
> "language": "python",
>
> "argv": [
>
> "/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda-4.2.0/bin/python",
>
> "-m",
>
> "ipykernel",
>
> "-f",
>
> "{connection_file}"
>
> ]
>
> }

6. After noticing the notebook failed on import pyspark, I added env section as below to the kernel.json:

> ```
> {
>
>  "display_name": "Python (rxie20181012-pyspark)",
>
>  "language": "python",
>
>  "argv": [
>
>   "/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda-4.2.0/bin/python",
>
>   "-m",
>
>   "ipykernel",
>
>   "-f",
>
>   "{connection_file}"
>
>  ],
>
>  "env": {
>
>   "HADOOP_CONF_DIR": "/etc/spark2/conf/yarn-conf",
>
>   "PYSPARK_PYTHON":"/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda/bin/python",
>
>   "SPARK_HOME": "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2",
>
>   "PYTHONPATH": "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2/lib/spark2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip:/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2/lib/spark2/python/",
>
>   "PYTHONSTARTUP": "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2/lib/spark2/python/pyspark/shell.py",
>
>   "PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS": " --master yarn --deploy-mode client pyspark-shell"
>
>  }
>
> }
> ```

Now no more error on import pyspark, but still not able to start a sparksession:

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('abc').getOrCreate()
```

> OSErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>   ----> 1 spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('abc').getOrCreate()
>
> /opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2/lib/spark2/python/pyspark/sql/session.pyc
>   in getOrCreate(self)
>       171                     for key, value in self._options.items():
>       172                         sparkConf.set(key, value)
>   --> 173                     sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
>       174                     # This SparkContext may be an existing one.
>       175                     for key, value in self._options.items():
>
> /opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2/lib/spark2/python/pyspark/context.pyc in
>   getOrCreate(cls, conf)
>       341         with SparkContext._lock:
>       342             if SparkContext._active_spark_context is None:
>   --> 343                 SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
>       344             return SparkContext._active_spark_context
>       345
>
> /opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2/lib/spark2/python/pyspark/context.pyc in
>   **init**(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, gateway, jsc, profiler_cls)
>       113         """
>       114         self._callsite = first_spark_call() or CallSite(None, None, None)
>   --> 115         SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
>       116         try:
>       117             self._do_init(master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer,
>
> /opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2/lib/spark2/python/pyspark/context.pyc in
>   _ensure_initialized(cls, instance, gateway, conf)
>       290         with SparkContext._lock:
>       291             if not SparkContext._gateway:
>   --> 292                 SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
>       293                 SparkContext._jvm = SparkContext._gateway.jvm
>       294
>
> /opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2/lib/spark2/python/pyspark/java_gateway.pyc
>   in launch_gateway(conf)
>        81                 def preexec_func():
>        82                     signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)
>   ---> 83                 proc = Popen(command, stdin=PIPE, preexec_fn=preexec_func, env=env)
>        84             else:
>        85                 # preexec_fn not supported on Windows
>
> /opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda/lib/python2.7/subprocess.pyc in
>   **init**(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines,
>   startupinfo, creationflags)
>       709                                 p2cread, p2cwrite,
>       710                                 c2pread, c2pwrite,
>   --> 711                                 errread, errwrite)
>       712         except Exception:
>       713             # Preserve original exception in case os.close raises.
>
> /opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda/lib/python2.7/subprocess.pyc in
>   _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, to_close,
>   p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite)    1341
>   raise    1342                 child_exception = pickle.loads(data)
>   -> 1343                 raise child_exception    1344     1345
>
> OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Can anyone help me to sort it out please? Thank you from bottom of my heart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

root cause identified and its working now:

> "SPARK_HOME": "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2"

should be replaced by:

> "SPARK_HOME": "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2/lib/spark2"